# Regex match last whole number

Tags: regex, numbers, range

I need to extract the last number from strings like

```
10-20 days // should extract 20
from 10 to 30 days // should extract 30
between 5 and 12 days //should extract 12
```

Iv tried with this pattern ^.+([0-9]+)[^\d]*days.*$ but it takes only the last digit not the whole number.

Comment: remove `^.+` from the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [Positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
\d+(?=\D*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                           times)
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 2):

### Best option:

You need a look-ahead assertion, like this:

```
(\d+)(?=\D*$)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vW9yT3/1)

### Alternative option:

Or you can modify your current pattern with a `?`:

```
^.+?([0-9]+)[^\d]days.?$
```

The first `?` makes the `.+` non-greedy. Also note the ending `?` - you don't have any characters after `days` in your examples. [**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dL2mR6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

Or this:

```
.*(?:\D|^)(\d+)
```

Hope it helps! 
Keep on coding, 
Ares.